# Converting column with LineString geometries to np.array

Tags: python, geopandas, linestring, numpy, array

I have a GeoDataFrame of a street network with the geometry of each row as a LineString. Say something like:

```
    type    id  tags    geometry    lanes   bridge  name    highway
0   way 34953479    {'access': 'private', 'highway': 'service', 'i...   LINESTRING (282025.712 6242798.110, 282029.830...   2.0 None    Engineering Way service
1   way 34953670    {'access': 'private', 'highway': 'service', 'i...   LINESTRING (281935.657 6242783.921, 281936.328...   2.0 None    Science Way service
```

I want each vertex as a row in a [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

With

```py
pt = [ np.array(line.coords) for line in rd.geometry ]
print(pt)
```

I get:

```
[array([[ 282025.71154782, 6242798.11011274],[ 282029.82990925, 6242798.7208016 ],[ 282033.94827067, 6242799.33149047],...
```

which is a `list` of `np.array`.

`pt[0]` is: `array([[ 282025.71154782, 6242798.11011274],[ 282029.82990925, 6242798.7208016 ],[ 282033.94827067, 6242799.33149047],...`

`pt[1]` is: `array([[ 281935.65690061, 6242783.92136821],[ 281936.32837562, 6242780.16379144],[ 281936.99985063, 6242776.40621467],...`

I want **one** `np.array` with the coordinates stacked.

How do I extract/convert a gdf of LineString geometry into **one** `np.array` where the coordinates are stacked

```
array([[ x, y],[ x, y ],[ x, y],...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a native NumPy's method [`concatenate()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

> Join a sequence of arrays along an existing axis.

```py
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

d = {
    'attr1': ['line1', 'line2'],
    'geometry': [
         LineString([
             (350630.319649, 5333438.389906),
             (410389.192817, 5298093.202727),
             (466139.848883, 5303194.569949),
             (500391.885943, 5310482.237409),
             (522254.888322, 5300643.886338),
             (547761.72443, 5287890.468284),
             (594038.412798, 5288254.851657),
             (620638.399026, 5307931.553798),
             (643230.16815, 5355301.392285)
             ]),
         LineString([
             (465059.389802, 5337643.246403),
             (428840.7437, 5395427.193238)]
             )]
    }

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d, crs="EPSG:25832")

pt = list(gdf.geometry) #[<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x000001F3F082FD00>, <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x000001F3F0822CA0>]
# pt = gdf.geometry.tolist() 

pt_array = np.concatenate(pt)

print(type(pt_array))
print(pt_array)
```

The above code will result in:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[ 350630.319649 5333438.389906]
 [ 410389.192817 5298093.202727]
 [ 466139.848883 5303194.569949]
 [ 500391.885943 5310482.237409]
 [ 522254.888322 5300643.886338]
 [ 547761.72443  5287890.468284]
 [ 594038.412798 5288254.851657]
 [ 620638.399026 5307931.553798]
 [ 643230.16815  5355301.392285]
 [ 465059.389802 5337643.246403]
 [ 428840.7437   5395427.193238]]
```